# Checkbox not functioning in ASPX form

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I click the checkbox, there are no tick sign. What is wrong with my code?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">..</asp:Content>  
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" Runat="Server">

<div class="col1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col2">Password Composition</div>
<div class="col3">:</div>
<div id="cb" class="col4">
    <input type="checkbox" runat="server"/>
    Alphabet &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input type="checkbox" runat="server" />
    Numeric &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input type="checkbox" runat="server" />
    Symbol 
</div>
</div>

... </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Javascript" Runat="Server">...</asp:Content>
```

This is my css for checkbox:

```
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

This form inherits from master page. Should I use < asp:Checkbox /> ? but I didn't know how to use them. Do give me an example that suit with my cases.

Comment: Please check if some css is not causing this ?

Comment: It is not aspx checkbox ,it is normal html.use <asp:checkbox> because you are also using runat=server ...

Comment: This is my css for that checkbox, @leopard. Is there anything wrong here?

    input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: _"Do give me an example that suit with my cases. If my code was wrong, then please correct it."_ This is a community to help you solving specific problems (see [ask]), not to fix your code for you. The way you asked for a fix sounds quite rude-ish, please consider editing it. Anyway, hopefully someone can give you a comprehensive answer that **helps you fixing your code**, but please do not expect anyone to fix your code for you.

Comment: ok. thank you for reminding me, @paul.

Answer (score 1):

I know my problem already. The script below, inside the masterpage caused other elements' click event malfunction. When I remove it, then my checkbox functioning.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if ( $(e.target).parents('.menu-wrapper').length == 0 && $('.menu-wrapper').is(':visible'))
{
$('.menu-wrapper').toggle('slide');
return false;
}
});
```

thanks everyone for helping.